# How Can i add a dynamic image(pie chart image or bar graph image) to pdf using itext

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, pdf-generation, itext

my program is generating a piechart, i need to add this piechart image to the pdf, when user tries to download page as pdf?

The page is nothing but a jsp which displays the piechart.

I'm using itext to generate pdf?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how the piechart is generated? What API, what content-type is it?

Comment: Save the pie-chart as an image server-side. Add it to the PDF. Put the generated PDF in the response. Done!

Comment: I'm displaying this piechart in a jsp, when the user clicks on export to pdf, i need to add all the contents of jsp including piechart in pdf.

my question is how can i add the piechart to pdf using itext API.

Comment: I'm using itext API because i need to do some formatting for the contents in PDF

Comment: Where is the pie-chart generated? Client-side or server-side?

Comment: server-side, i'm using chartsservlet.

Comment: What is Chartsservlet? Is it this: http://docs.sonarsource.org/1.5/apidocs/org/sonar/web/charts/ChartsServlet.html Provide a link to the product. Or even better: tell us if the chart is a PNG or any other image format. Importing such an image into a PDF using iText is a piece of cake, but if you don't show us what you've tried, your question risks to be downvoted or closed.

Comment: It is an api for generating piecharts from IBM, the piechart is shown as a image(png), can you tell how i can add this image to pdf.